# How to write concurrent program in clojure using ref, agent, and future?

Tags: clojure

I am writing a program that allows two futures  to transfer money from account A to account B. Each future will try to transfer its amount and sleep for a while after that. My program compiled with No Error, so I don't know where to start debugging it. It is supposed to print out text, but it does not. Can someone tell me what is happening with my program?

```
   ;here are initial amounts of balance A and B
   (def balanceA {ref 1000})
   (def balanceB {ref 2000})

   ;agent will count a number of complete transfer
   (def agentCount {agent 1})

   ; this func will do the transfer with the waitingTime/sleep
   (defn transfer [balanceA balanceB amount futureNum waitingTime]
    )

   ; Two futures will repeat 10 times doing the transactions and print out the balances
   (dotimes [n 10](def futureA (future transfer(balanceA balanceB 20 1 (rand-int 100)) (prn "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))

   (dotimes [n 10](def futureB (future transfer(balanceA balanceB 15 2 (rand-int 40))(prn "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))

   (shutdown-agents)
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**: thanks to @noisesmith comment/correction!

Only you have a displaced parenthesis  on your transfer call and an error on your ref and agent definitions

The error definition: {ref 1000} or {agent 1} instead of (ref 1000) (agent 1)
    (def balanceA (ref 1000))
    (def balanceB (ref 2000))
    (def agentCount (agent 1))

and the parenthesis ...

(future transfer **(** balanceA ... => (future transfer  balanceA ...

You have to change this:

```
   (dotimes [n 10](def futureA (future transfer(balanceA balanceB 20 1 (rand-int 100)) (prn "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))

   (dotimes [n 10](def futureB (future transfer(balanceA balanceB 15 2 (rand-int 40))(prn "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))
```

With this:

```
   (dotimes [n 10](def futureA (future (transfer balanceA balanceB 20 1 (rand-int 100)) (print "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))

   (dotimes [n 10](def futureB (future (transfer balanceA balanceB 15 2 (rand-int 40))(prn "result" @balanceA @balanceB))))
```

Comment: I think this nesting is still wrong. If the transfer function needs to be applied to those args, the correct syntax is `(future (transfer balanceA...))` the version here simply puts transfer, balanceA, balanceB, 15, etc. in an implicit do block and fails to use any of them meaningfully.